My Script inside my model's part doesn't run when I clone it
This is my code for spawning in the model itself which is located in ReplicatedStorage, which this is the hierarchy:
SpawnDoor (Model)
Door (Sound)
Light (Folder)
Door1 (Part)
Door2 (Part)
Part (Part)
SurfaceLight (SurfaceLight)
Teleport (Script) --script that doesn't work when door spawns in
Wood (Folder)
Door1 (Model)
Union
Door2 (Model)
Union
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local CameraShaker = require(ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("CameraShaker"))

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local playerGui = player.PlayerGui.Red.Red

local Camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera

local cooldown = false  -- Cooldown flag
local cooldownTime = 2  -- Cooldown time in seconds

local function ShakeCamera(shakCf)
    Camera.CFrame = Camera.CFrame * shakCf
end

local renderPriority = Enum.RenderPriority.Camera.Value + 1
local camShake = CameraShaker.new(renderPriority, ShakeCamera)

camShake:Start()

-- Function to handle J key press
local function onKeyPress(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.J then
        if cooldown then
            print("Tool is on cooldown")

            -- Shake camera and show GUI
            camShake:ShakeOnce(60, 80, 1, 1)  -- Adjust parameters as needed

            local transparencyTweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(1, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, 0, false, 0)

            local tween1 = TweenService:Create(playerGui, transparencyTweenInfo, {
                BackgroundTransparency = 0.3
            })

            local tween2 = TweenService:Create(playerGui, transparencyTweenInfo, {
                BackgroundTransparency = 1
            })

            tween1:Play()
            tween1.Completed:Connect(function()
                tween2:Play()
            end)

            return
        end

        cooldown = true  -- Activate cooldown

        print("Tool Activated")  -- Check if this prints when you use the tool

        game.SoundService.Biwa:Play()

        local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
        local Char = Player.Character
        if not Char then
            print("Character not found")
            cooldown = false  -- Reset cooldown if an error occurs
            return
        end

        local HRP = Char:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if not HRP then
            print("HumanoidRootPart not found")
            cooldown = false  -- Reset cooldown if an error occurs
            return
        end

        local DoorModel = game.ReplicatedStorage.SpawnDoor
        if not DoorModel or not DoorModel:IsA("Model") then
            print("SpawnDoor Model not found in ReplicatedStorage or not a Model")
            cooldown = false  -- Reset cooldown if an error occurs
            return
        end

        -- Raycast to find the ground below the player
        local rayOrigin = HRP.Position
        local rayDirection = Vector3.new(0, -100, 0)  -- Cast downwards
        local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
        raycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = {Char}
        raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist

        local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(rayOrigin, rayDirection, raycastParams)

        if not raycastResult then
            print("No ground detected below the player")
            cooldown = false  -- Reset cooldown if an error occurs
            return
        end

        local groundPosition = raycastResult.Position

        local door = DoorModel:Clone()
        door.Parent = workspace

        -- Set the PrimaryPart of the door model
        door.PrimaryPart = door:FindFirstChild("Light").Part

        if not door.PrimaryPart then
            print("PrimaryPart not found in DoorModel")
            door:Destroy()
            cooldown = false  -- Reset cooldown if an error occurs
            return
        end

        -- Set the position of the door model to the ground position
        door:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(groundPosition))

        print("Door spawned at:", door.PrimaryPart.Position)

        -- Delay before sliding doors open
        wait(2)

        -- Animation to slide open doors
        local door1 = door.Wood.Door1
        local door2 = door.Wood.Door2

        if door1 and door2 then

            if door1.Union and door2.Union then
                -- Tween for Door1
                local door1OpenCFrame = door1.Union.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, -5)  -- Example: Move 5 studs to the right
                local door1Tween = TweenService:Create(door1.Union, TweenInfo.new(0.2), {CFrame = door1OpenCFrame})

                -- Tween for Door2
                local door2OpenCFrame = door2.Union.CFrame * CFrame.new(0, 0, 5)  -- Example: Move 5 studs to the left
                local door2Tween = TweenService:Create(door2.Union, TweenInfo.new(0.2), {CFrame = door2OpenCFrame})

                door1Tween:Play()
                door2Tween:Play()

                game.SoundService.Door:Play()
            else
                print("Primary part not found in one of the doors")
            end
        else
            print("One of the doors not found in DoorModel")
        end

        print("Doors sliding open")
        task.wait(1)
        -- Destroy the door model after a delay
        repeat
            door.Wood.Door1.Union.Transparency += 0.01
            door.Wood.Door2.Union.Transparency += 0.01
            door.Light.Part.Transparency += 0.01
            door.Light.Door1.Transparency += 0.01
            door.Light.Door2.Transparency += 0.01
            task.wait(0.01)
        until door.Wood.Door1.Union.Transparency >= 1
        door:Destroy()
        print("Door destroyed after 3 seconds")

        -- Start cooldown timer
        task.delay(cooldownTime, function()
            cooldown = false
            print("Cooldown ended")
        end)
    end
end

-- Connect the function to the key press event
game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(onKeyPress)

I've tried to clone it from the workspace instead as well as trying to have a constantly updating server script that checks for the door to spawn in and then does the action I wanted, I even replaced the script with a simple print script for all cases to see if maybe my code was wrong but nothing seems to work.

If this script is local (which I think it is). When you clone a local script it stops working, for some reason. Try having the clone and script you posted server-sided. I had this same issue some time ago. Hope this helps :)
